# find the rank of the given matix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix of order $n$ where $A=(A_{ij})$ and $A_{ij} = \min\{i,j\}$. Find rank of $A$. I am trying to find rows which generate the whole matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Denote your matrix by $A_n$. Then 
$$
\pmatrix{ 1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
1 & 2 &\dots & 2 \\
\vdots\\
1 & 2 & \dots & n
}.
$$
Substracting the first row from all other rows yields
$$
A_n = \pmatrix{ 1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
0 & 1 &\dots & 1 \\
\vdots\\
0 & 1 & \dots & n-1 
} = \pmatrix {1 & 1\dots 1 \\  0 & A_{n-1}}.
$$
It follows $rank(A_n) = rank(A_{n-1})+1$. Since $rank(A_1)=1$, we obtain $rank(A_n)=n$.

Comment: Sweet! Well done Sir.